# sbt ClassNotFoundException dependencyOverrides

Tags: scala, playframework, dependencies, sbt

I have a dependency that needs `dependencyOverrides`.

All dependencies are resolved correctly (displayed in Intellij and listed when running `show runtime:fullClasspath` in sbt console.

But whenever I `sbt run` I get the following Exception:
[image]

I created a small project to reproduce the problem:

https://github.com/pme123/play-birt-example

Just run the `HomeControllerSpec`.

What did I miss?

Comment: Without a complete example having the same issue it's hard to say what is wrong here...

Comment: @Christian I created a small project to reproduce the problem! see https://github.com/pme123/play-birt-example

Comment: Thanks for the project. I can reproduce the problem when doing sbt test. Unfortunately I couldn't find out what's the cause of it.